# 再利用されているページを表示した際に関数をコールしたい

Tags: angular2, angular4

RouteReuseStrategyを使用し、Backを押し前のページに戻る際にはページを再利用するようにしていますが
Backで戻った際にngOnInit(),ngAfterViewInit()がCallされないようなので、ページ再突入時のトリガを掴むことができません。

Angularのlifecycleにもそれらしきハンドラがないようなのですが
何か方法ございますでしょうか？

Comment: constructor()がCallされますか？コードの例がありますか？Stackblitzなど。